# css is prioritised by direction, requires !importrant?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this code:

```
[dir="ltr"] [icon-start] icon {
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}

[dir="rtl"] [icon-start] icon {
  padding-left: 0.3em;
}

.custom-icon {
  padding: 0;
}
```

And when I do:

```
<div dir="ltr">
  <div icon-start>
    <icon class="custom-icon"></icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

The icon element combines the first and the third rules to be padding of `0 0.3em 0 0`

This is not the desired behavior. I want css to work normally as it always does, and have the last rule be the shot-caller.

2 possible solutions, that are not welcomed:

- add =`!important` to `.custom-icon` - not welcomed, as I want to minimise the use of `!important` + I structured my code such that I don't need to use important.
- add directional rules for `.custom-icon`. undesired because it bloats my bundle size (this needs to happen in like a 1000 places), it is not very friendly, and generally can be misunderstood.

Something like:

```
[dir="ltr"] .custom-icon, [dir="rtl"] .custom-icon {
  padding: 0
}
```

Is there a way I can tell css to ignore `[dir]` rules in the priority structure?

Comment: Well no, because they're specific attribute selectors...

Comment: [Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: "I structured my code such that I don't need to use important." Well clearly that's not the case here, judging by your predicament.

Comment: @BoltClock what I meant is that without adding the directions, it is structured in a way that it would work with no important. Now, I guess I'll need to adjust to the specificity..

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can tell css to ignore `[dir]` rules in the priority structure?

No, you can't have one rule delete arbitrary other rules from the cascade.

You're going to have to match the specificity of the other rules if `!important` is not an option:

```
[dir] [icon-start] .custom-icon {
  padding: 0;
}
```

(Technically, you'd also need the `icon` type selector to really match the specificity of the other rules, but since a class selector is more specific anyway the type selector is not necessary.)

Alternatively, you could exclude `.custom-icon` from the other rules so you don't have to worry about overriding them:

```
[dir="ltr"] [icon-start] icon:not(.custom-icon) {
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}

[dir="rtl"] [icon-start] icon:not(.custom-icon) {
  padding-left: 0.3em;
}
```